# Java how to stop if statement continuation after a condition is met?

Tags: java

This is my first question on this site. If it's not appropriate here, I'd like a link to a better place to ask it (please).

I have a big chain of if statements that all execute even when I print an error message beforehand when a certain condition is met. How do I stop the rest from executing when `if (myVar >= 0)` is true?

Ok, here's a small example (I basically want the code to stop if "error" happens, sorry if there's too little that it doesn't make sense):

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int num = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
int bigN;
String answer;
    if (num>=0)
      System.out.println("error");

  bigN = num*20;
  if (bigN>=80){
  answer = ("something");
}
  else
System.out.println("args[0] is " + answer)
```

Comment: Are you trying to exit nested ifs, or just skip to the end of a bunch of checks?

Comment: Please include an example code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please add a [mcve] to your question.  At first sight, it seems that a simple `if ( myVar >= 0 ) { return; }` might do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to put a `return` statement.

If all of these are in your main loop, I would say pull them out into another module, like a method or function that is performing checks, and import it back in.

But you can set multiple [returns](https://www.javatpoint.com/return-keyword-in-java). The method you are running will stop on the first return it hits.

Comment: Might also consider continue or break statement, possibly with a label, if operating in a loop.

Comment: No loops were mentioned, which is why I didn't mention continue or break, but yes, you are right.

Comment: @BenjaminBerman I wonder if I can just add break; I edited my question to give a small example, Idk if it gets my point across

Comment: I just tried return; and it gave an error about an "unreachable statement"

Comment: In your case try `System.exit(0);` for stop process

Comment: @Cotton Headed Ninnymuggins (Love the name, btw) This is what I meant by it all being in your main loop. You can't return out of a `main` (well, you can it will just stop the script). It may have an unreachable statment due to missing/misplaced brackets `{ }`   Your `if (num>=0)` doesn't have any brackets after it, so if you put a return statment there, the code below it will *always* be unreachable.

Comment: System.exit[0] did the job, I might have to try that out sometime. Thanks for the name compliment ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can stop or avoid the rest of process with one of them examples

#### 1 Adding else statement in if

with `else` when

```java
if(...){
 // if pass here wont pass in next ones
}else if( ... ){
 // if pass here wont pass in next ones
}else{
 // it has passed because didn't pass in none of previous
}
```

#### 2 Return value on method and exit from function

```java
public String methodReturnString(...){
  if(...){
    return ""; // will return value to method and wont run next if
  }

  if(...){
    return ""; // will return value to method and wont continue the rest of method
  }

}
```

#### 3 Return void on method and exit from function

the same last one but only exit method

```java
public void methodWithNoReturn(...){
  if(...){
    return; // will return and wont run next if
  }

  if(...){
    return; // will return and wont continue the rest of method
  }

}
```

#### 4 exit on throwing error

```java
public void someMethod(...) throws RuntimeException{
  if(...){
     // if pass here will exit from method but will throw error to be handled  in other method
     throw new RuntimeException("some error);
  }

}
```

Comment: You don't want to throw an Exception as part of your regular code path - that's just bad coding and should be avoided.